# PHP cURL - Incorrect schema for json request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to implement following cURL request in php:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: login:password" \
-d '{"phone": "+48667421797", "msg": "Great app! Thank you!"}' \
https://some.endpoint.url
```

It works fine in console, I also managed to use this request in tools like postman/insomnia.

But when I try to implement it in `PHP` like that:

```
    $fields = [
        'phone' => $number,
        'msg'   => $msg,
    ];

    $data = json_encode($fields);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: login:password'
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                    
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, config('kajaki.sms_url'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);


    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I get `400: Incorrect schema` which AFAIK indicates, that the request is not being sent as valid JSON request.

What is wrong? How can I send this request correctly as a JSON?

Unfortunately this API does not provide any documentation.

Comment: try to print $data and check whether it is valid json or not

Comment: It is correct. I tried

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before, I don't know if it will work for you but you can try `addslashes()` like this:

```
$fields = [
    'phone' => "+48667421797",
    'msg'   => "Great app! Thank you!",
];

$data = addslashes(json_encode($fields)); 
// outputs {\"phone\":\"+48667421797\",\"msg\":\"Great app! Thank you!\"}
```

Comment: I'm not getting 400/Incorrect schema anymore, but the server response is empty, as if the request was not recognized at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little test script which prints the received JSON string, then test both the CLI curl command and your implementation against the test script. Is the received JSON data the same? If not, what is different in the data from the PHP implementation?

**index.php**

```
<?php
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

**Run test webserver**

```
cd directory/containing/index.php
php -S localhost:12345
```

**Send data with cURL on CLI**

```
user@host $ curl -X POST \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -H "Authorization: login:password" \
> -d '{"phone": "+48667421797", "msg": "Great app! Thank you!"}' \
> http://localhost:12345
string(57) "{"phone": "+48667421797", "msg": "Great app! Thank you!"}"
```

**Send data with cURL via PHP**

```
// Modify the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:12345');
```

If the JSON data is the same, you should also consider if other parts of the request might be invalid, for example the HTTP headers or the URL.